# Filter out non-aplhanumeric characters within Bash brace expansion

Tags: bash, variable-expansion, brace-expansion

Is it possible to modify an environment variable prior to expanding it?

Example:

```
set ENV_VAR=some-stuff

echo ${ENV_VAR} - get this to print "somestuff" instead of "some-stuff"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ ENV_VAR=some-stuff
$ echo ${ENV_VAR//[^a-zA-Z]}
somestuff
```

Parameter expansion (that's the proper terminology for what you call "brace expansion", which is actually something else entirely) accepts *modifiers*, such as making the first character (or all characters) lower- or upper-case, eliminating a prefix or a suffix, and replacing a pattern with some other string (or with the null string). See "Parameter expansion" in the [section "Expansion"](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc13) in the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/bash.1.html).